# Critical pattern in nagios

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I have to monitor the string HTTP/1.1" 404 in nagios. So i am using check_logfiles plugin to create the monitor. I have created the defination below

```
        define service {
        service_description            Logfile_xyz 404 exception
        host_name                      xyz
        use                            generic-service
        check_command                  check_logfiles!/logfile pathpath !\\`hostname\\`_404Exception!\\\'HTTP/1.1\\" 404\\\'!6
        check_interval                 10
        contact_groups                 tivoli_xyz_high
        max_check_attempts             2
        retry_interval                 2
        servicegroups                  project_b2v_details_availability
     }
```

But i am getting the below error
 --tag=`hostname`_404Exception --criticalpattern=\'HTTP/1.1" 404\' --criticalthreshold=6 --htmlencode' returned status 2

Any idea how to fix

Comment: First of all, try run script check_logfiles with your parameters on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

We can use HTTP/1.1. 404 instead of HTTP/1.1" 404